# rubymine complaining about rails controller scaffold syntax

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax, rubymine, hashrocket

I'm scaffolding with rails, and the following code is being generated

```
format.json { render json: @leg, status: :created, location: @leg }
```

But RubyMine is complaining unless I switch it to

```
format.json { render :json => @leg, :status => :created, :location => @leg }
```

Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: It's just the SDK being out of date that it's using to parse with, see answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-12466 suggests that you set the SDK to ruby 1.9 to get this working.